# simulation of mixture GARCH models

Tags: simulation, garch, mixture-distribution

I want to simulate data that follow a mixture - GARCH specification.

The conditional density of the return series $r_t $, based on information up to time t is given by
$ f_{t-1}(r_t;\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^k w_if(r_t;\theta_i) $
where f is an appropriate distribution pdf, like Gaussian or Student-t.
I have estimated the parameters of the model with ML. I know how to simulate data from a (single) GARCH process but what about the mixture? Should I just simulate data from each component and use the mixing weights $w_i $ to create the data?

Any ideas or appropriate references would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After a little more searching I found a solution. It goes like that: (Let's assume 2 components)
*Simulate a sample of a process $r_t $ that follows a mixture-GARCH specification:*

Simulate two independent GARCH processes, $r_{t1},r_{t2} $ of size t = 1,2,...,T

For each i = 1,2,...,T

simulate u~$ U(0,1)$

if u<$w_1$ then $r_t = r_{1t}$, else $r_t = r_{2t}$

end

Is this correct? Thank you